# While loop not outputting to a log file

Tags: shell, logs

I am making in-roads to getting a curl script to work as intended, working around some issue that requires pagination. My point is... the curl part works, BUT I can't get the output to log to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Author: Scouse Bob
# ----------------------------------------
log="/tmp/bob.log">>"${log}"

i=0
while [[ $i -lt 700 ]]
do curl -i -X GET "https://bob_server.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?jql=ORDER%20BY%20Created&maxResults=50&startAt=$i" --user bob@abcde.com:<token_id> --header Accept: application/json; (( i+=50 )); >>"${log}"; done
```

I have tested the above in various forms and if I take the log parts out, the script outputs to the screen.

Does anyone know why the loop won't output to the log I'm trying to create please?

Answer (score 7):

You have `>> "$log"`, but it does not receive any input as it comes after a `;`.

Either put it after `done`:

```
while ... do ... done >> "$log"
```

or after the `curl` command:

```bsh
curl ... >> "$log"; done
```

Note also, that you should quote your `--header` and `--user` string:

```
--header "Accept: application/json"
```

Also, you could more easily use a `for`-loop:

```
for i in $(seq 0 50 700); do ... done
```

---

In total:

```bsh
log="/tmp/bob.log">>"${log}"

for i in $(seq 0 50 700); do
    curl -i -X GET "https://bob_server.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?jql=ORDER%20BY%20Created&maxResults=50&startAt=$i" --user "bob@abcde.com:<token_id>" --header "Accept: application/json"
done >> "${log}"
```

or without `seq`:

```
for (( i=0; i <= 700; i += 50)); do
   ...
done
```